# Merge multiple columns from different files with a partial match via awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files, A and B with the columns separated by \.
Column **2** of file **A** is exactly the **same** as column **1** of file **B**.
I want to merge these two files keeping file B the same, add a new column based on the same fields between the two files and a partial match between column 1 of file A and column 2 of file B.

By partial match I mean something like this:

| File A (column 1) | File B (column 2) | A=B? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A? | True |
| A | Asd | True |
| B | B | True |
| C | c | True |
| C | CA | True |
| D | A | False |

**If** there are **values** with the **same column 1 and 2 in file A**, they must be **added to file B** separated by **;**

**File A**
A\2022.10.10\note a
A\2022.10.10\note b
B\2022.10.14\note c
A\2022.10.14\note d
C\2022.10.15\note e

**File B**
2022.10.10\A?
2022.10.14\B?
2022.10.14\a
2022.10.15\C
2022.10.15\D

**Desired output**
2022.10.10\A?\note a;note b\
2022.10.14\B?\note c\
2022.10.14\a\note d\
2022.10.15\C\note e\
2022.10.15\D\

How can I do this with awk?

Comment: Why is "note d" from file B not merged with "note a" and "note b", i.e. why is "A" == "A?" but not "A" == "a" in the desired output, but in the table it is stated that "C" == "c" is true? 
 
Can you explain if the matching is case sensitive or not, that means can the partial matching happen on uppercased values of the columns of both files? 

aka is `upper(file2_col2_value).startswith(upper(file1_col1_value)` the criterion?

Comment: Are the records defined as line position within each file or the date field?

Comment: @LarsFischer I apologize if it is explained in a confusing way. I will try to be more clear. Yes, it is case sensitive in both files. Partial matching only happens if the start is the same. Ex: [FileA = US/2022.10.22/note a] [FileB = 2022.10.22/USA] then the [desired output = 2022.10.22/USA/note a] because column 1 of file A is contained in column 2 of file B and they both start exactly the same. This is also why column 3 of file A (note a) is added to file B.

Comment: @Forky Considering the Desired output: why is "note d" with key "A" of line "A\2022.10.14\note d" from File A not appearing in the desired output after "note a;note b" which also belong to key "A" ?   What is the deal with the column that looks like a date in both files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awk script might work depending on the details of your requirements (e.g. of the keys are case sensitive or not).

An awk script like this might work:

```
function make_key(k) 
{
    # either return k or an uppercase version for case-insensitive keys
    # return k;
    return toupper(k);
}

BEGIN { 
    FS="\\";
}

NR==FNR {
    key=make_key($2 "\\" $1);
    if( key in notes){
        notes[key]=notes[key] ";" $3
    }
    else {
        notes[key]=$3
    }
        
}

NR!=FNR {
    for(k in notes){
         pos=index(make_key($0),k);
         if(pos==1){
            printf "%s%s%s%s\n",  $0, FS, notes[k], FS;
            next;
         }
    }
    print $0 FS;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
awk -f script.awk file_A file_B
```

In the function make_key you can configure the case sensitiveness by either returning k or an uppercase version.

The `NF==FNR` block is used during reading the first file (file_A) here the notes are stored under a key made out of the second and first column. Notes are appended if the key is already existing.

In the `NF!=FNR` block the second file (file_B) is read. Here we print the line of file_b and the matching notes by comparing every key if the line of file_B starts with the key. If no key matches, then only the line of file_B is printed.

The `BEGIN` block just sets up the field separator.

Answer (score 0):

To process the first file, we could use condition `NR==FNR`. During the first file processing, I used two hash tables, namely `pattern_ht` to store column 1 values in lower case and `note_ht` to store column 3 values. Since date string itself is not unique to serve as key, we will use the concatenation of columns 2 and 3 as key for both hash tables.

When processing the second file, firstly check if date string matches column 1 exactly after performing a split of the key string. If matched, perform the partial matching of column 2 to `pattern_ht` values after converting to lower case. If it matches and this is the first match, record the `third_col` value. If it already has another value, append to it with ";". Finally, display accordingly:

```
awk -F'\' 'NR==FNR {pattern_ht[$2";"$3] = tolower($1); note_ht[$2";"$3] = $3; next} 
{third_col="";
for (key in pattern_ht) {
        split(key,date_str,";");
        if (date_str[1] == $1) {
                if (tolower($2) ~ pattern_ht[key]) { 
                        if (length(third_col) == 0) 
                                third_col = note_ht[key] 
                        else 
                                third_col = third_col ";" note_ht[key]
                }
        }
}
if (length(third_col) != 0)
        print $1"\\"$2"\\"third_col"\\"
else
        print $1"\\"$2"\\"
}' fileA fileB
```

Here is the output:

```
2022.10.10\A?\note a;note b\
2022.10.14\B?\note c\
2022.10.14\a\note d\
2022.10.15\C\note e\
2022.10.15\D\
```